# SQL reduce the amout of selects on table

Tags: oracle11g, query-performance

I have a performance problem with my SQL query: (on Oracle SQL)

```
Data:
- step:number
- processid:number
- Status:number
- process_planed:number

- id:primary
- ... and many more
```

The result of all rows dedicated to a specific processid (4711):

```
step   |processid  |Status   |Process_planned |....
---------------------------------------------------
10     |4711       |30       | 75             |....
20     |4711       |50       | 81             |....
30     |4711       |10       | 81             |....
40     |4711       |10       | 36             |....
50     |4711       |10       | 25             |....
```

My database is full of such data. The problem is that, the step value isn't fixed. It can also be:

```
260,310,570,600 ...
```

Now I want to get to every data which has process_planned = 75 and Status = 10, but I want only these processes, which have the very first entry (in example above step 10) equal 10. My solution was the following:

- 1 query for getting all rows with process_planned = 75 with distinct processid
- Now I have all process which are involved to process_id = 75
- Then I do a sub-query for each process_id, which checks if the first step is related to process_planned = 75 and if the Status = 10
- Then I write this single data in a Array.

Now the problem is my solution has a lack of Performance! e.g. 40 processid's with each 6 steps I do with my solution 241 queries! There must be an easier way to do this.

But I have no idea, if the step would be fixed it would be easy, then only have to add where step = 10 to get the very first steps.

Have you an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186734.aspx) to find the first record for each process id?

You can use row number to rank the returned records for each process id.  You can then filter for the top rank.

[Example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/402419/row-number-example)

```
WITH SampleDate AS
    (
        /* This CTE returns some example records.
         */
        SELECT
            r.*
        FROM
            (
                VALUES    
                    (10, 4711, 30, 75),
                    (20, 4711, 50, 81),
                    (30, 4711, 10, 75),
                    (40, 4711, 10, 75),
                    (50, 4711, 10, 25)
            ) AS r(Step, ProcessId, [Status], Processed_Planned)
    )
/* Main query returns the first row for 
 * each process id with a planned of 75
 * and a status of 10.
 */
SELECT
    r.*
FROM
    (
        /* This sub query ranks the steps from each 
         * procsss id.
         */
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProcessId ORDER BY Step) AS RowNumber,
            *
        FROM
            SampleDate
        WHERE
            Processed_Planned = 75
            AND [Status] = 10
    ) AS r
WHERE
    RowNumber = 1 
;
```

Comment: THANKS for the quick answer: i've changed the code for my Needs, but i get the follwing exception: "missing right parenthesis"    i should say, that i use Oracle sql

Comment: Sounds like a typo.  You probably have one more ( than ) in your code.  
I tested the example in SQL Server.  The Oracle docs for ROW_NUMBER can be found below.  Not sure if there are any differences.  You should probably remove SQL Server from the tags.  It increases the odds of receiving an answer than does not work for you.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are asking for the lowest value of `step` where `process_planned = 75` and `status = 10`, in which case you can do

```
SELECT MIN(step) AS step, processid, status, process_planned
FROM data
WHERE process_planned = 75 AND status = 10
GROUP BY processid, status, process_planned;
```